# Insert value into an old identity field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which had an identity column.
for many reasons we had to remove the identity from that column.
I have a system that inserts a value to that table by the old way, passes null for the identity column.
is there a simple way to define identity column to receive a value in case it is passed to it, and if a value of null is passed, to make that table to set a unique value to that field that is not found in that table (act like identity).

What i mean is, if there is value, insert it. 
And if the system tries to insert null act like an identity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short no. You are going to have do a "roll your own" identity and this is always a problem because of concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger seems like a good choice for this situation, but there are a lot of ways you can handle the situation.

The example below creates an `INSTEAD OF` insert trigger that gets the columns that were supposed to be inserted, and generates a new value via a function if the ID column is null.

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON myTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO myTable (myIDcolumn, anotherColumn)
    SELECT COALESCE(myIDColumn, dbo.SomeMethodToCreateID), anotherColumn
    FROM inserted
```

How that `SomeTheodToCreateID` function is to work is up to you.  One thing you could do is change the SELECT to combine max plus row_number:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(myIDColumn, 
  (SELECT MAX(myIDColumn) FROM myTable) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY anotherColumn)
)
...
```

Comment: This about as good as this bad situation can get. This has the potential concurrency issues and this is dealing with the symptom rather than the problem but given the circumstances that is about all that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

DBCC CHECKIDENT ( '[dbo].[Customers]', RESEED, 1 )